# Removing specific items from Cache (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, caching

I am adding a bunch of items to the ASP.NET cache with a specific prefix.
I'd like to be able to iterate over the cache and remove those items.

The way I've tried to do it is like so:

```
    foreach (DictionaryEntry CachedItem in Cache)
    {
        string CacheKey = CachedItem.Key.ToString();
        if(CacheKey.StartsWith(CACHE_PREFIX){
            Cache.Remove(CacheKey);
        }
    }
```

Could I be doing this more efficiently?

I had considered creating a temp file and adding the items with a dependancy on the file, then just deleting the file. Is that over kill?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't remove items from a collection whilst you are iterating over it so you need to do something like this:

```
List<string> itemsToRemove = new List<string>();

IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = Cache.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    if (enumerator.Key.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(prefix))
    {
        itemsToRemove.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString());
    }
}

foreach (string itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
{
    Cache.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

This approach is fine and is quicker and easier than cache dependencies.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.
Thanks

Comment: Nicely done. Although, in next version of .NET I'd like to see Remove method on ALL collections that takes regular expression as input.

Comment: Access to ASP.NET cache is thread safe. Note that you are responsible for ensuring thread safety for the objects that you put in your cache, but the code in this case is just enumerating and removing.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a subclass of `CacheDependency` that does the invalidation appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep another item in cache for this purpose only. Let's say you cache 10.000 items with keys like: cache_prefix_XXX. So adding an item with just cache_prefix as its key and adding the rest of them with a dependency on this key you can control the removal of all of them. One thing to consider would be the priorities. Set that particular item a higher priority than the actual data items.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on number of your cache items and how often you do the cleanup. I would worry about it only if it actually was a performance issue - i.e. measure it.

Your solution is fine to me unless you're doing something extreme.

Answer (score 0):

For the cache clean up , I assume you need to run it manually when you notice there are too many cache items. 
Using MS lib cache block , it can do this work for you automatically. 
In the cachingConfiguration; you can set the property maximumElementsInCacheBeforeScavenging; once the number of cache items are over the limit then cache manager will clean out the cache automatically.